# Can you lock minecarts to be not able to move in Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Title says it all, I'm making a bedrock parkour map with minecarts so you can jump, right click on a minecart and continue. Is there a way to stop the minecart from nudging by the players?

Answer (score 1):

Make a repeating always active command block with the command:

```
tp @e[type=minecart,r=2,c=1,x=5,y=10,z=15] 5 10 15
```

Replace 5 with the X coord, 10 with the Y, and 15 with the Z.

Let me know how that works for you, if it doesn’t work how you’d like I might have another idea.

Comment: I would probably use square ranges with `dx`, `dy`, `dz` instead, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would to be to put the cart on top of a hopper with a rail in between, and then to break the rail. For parkour this would be an issue because you could land on the hopper. I dont think it is possible to get a minecart to simply float in the air. With the hopper, it will still move a little but not as much as if on a block or on a rail.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work but if it does that's a pretty crafty idea . Also though, the asker doesn't want them in the air, they just want the minecarts to be frozen in place.